# self contained javafx app - launch app with windows startup

Tags: intellij-idea, ant, javafx, wix, self-contained

I am using intellij ant and wix to build a .msi of a javafx client app
How do i set it up such that the app launches by itself everytime the user logins. I tried setting it up using wxi generated by wix.

Comment: figured it out http://anuzach.blogspot.in/2015/09/create-and-customize-msi-bundle.html